# Can anybody tell me why this endless while loop isn't working properly?

Tags: c, loops, variables, while-loop

```
int x;
x == 0;
while( x = 100 ){
    printf("Endless while loop");
}
```

I'm unsure as to why this loop isn't working as intended. I have set x equal to 0 so then the while loop should only run if x is equal to 100 (which it isn't). However the loop seems to run irrespective of this. This seems to happen with the while loop condition set to any value.

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks,
Dan.

Comment: Never post images of code. Paste the code as text. Use the editor help to learn how to format it correctly.

Comment: You mix up assignment operator with equality comparison, switch = and ==

Comment: That said: `==` is comparison, `=` is assignment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

== is used for equivalency, whereas = is used for assigning a variable.

Change your code to the following for it to work:

```
int x;
x = 0;
while(x == 100) {
  printf("this will not print");
}
```

Comment: Ah okay thank you so much :)